# New 256GB SDCARD gnome-disk said that is a 249 GB Drive. Is broken?

Tags: disk, partitioning, sd-card

I have bought my new Kingston 256 GB SDCard.
But Gnome Disk Utility is able to see only 249 GB?

I'd like to know if it is normal and why.

Thanks you

Comment: Are you mixing GiB and GB. Or have you formatted it which then uses space just for the formatting? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte#Consumer_confusion

Comment: gnome-disk, and my sdcard display "GB" (base10) not GiB (base 8). So I think that I don't mixing GB and GiB. Probably gnome-disk does.

Answer (score 1):

No.  It's a different way of calculating.  Storage on computers if often calculated in powers of two.  Humans calculate in powers of 10.  In small numbers, that doesn't show.  But in large sizes it shows.

Comment: IMHO, probably GUI should use GiB instead. Because GB is base 10.

Comment: Well, you can have your opinion, but it's pretty much accepted as tradition in the industry.